# Promisifying bcrypt-nodejs with Bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using NodeJS, with bcrypt-nodejs (https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs) and Bluebird for promises. Came up with this code and been wondering if there is better way to do the same thing. I have module with:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird"),
    bcrypt = Promise.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt-nodejs'));

// ....[some othe code here]

    Users.prototype.setPassword = function(user) {

        return bcrypt.genSaltAsync(10).then(function(result) {
            return bcrypt.hashAsync(user.password, result);
        });

    };
```

then from another module I call `users.setPassword` as below:

```
app.post('/api/v1/users/set-password', function(req, res, next) {
    users.setPassword(req.body).then(function(result) {

        // Store hash in your password DB.
        console.log(result[1]);

        res.json({
            success: true
        })
    })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

It always ends up with "[Error: No callback function was given.]" message as `bcrypt.hashAsync` seems to require 4 parameters. Original, non-promisified `hash` method requires 3 only though. When I add empty callback to `hashAsync`, it works fine:

```
Users.prototype.setPassword = function(user) {

    return bcrypt.genSaltAsync(10).then(function(result) {
        return bcrypt.hashAsync(user.password, result,function() {});
    });

};
```

Is there any better way to do this, without providing empty callback as above?

EDIT:

In response to Bergi's comment.. the function will set password eventually, I just didn't get that far when posted the question. Now got this far, please let me know if something is not quite right though:

```
 Users.prototype.setPassword = function(user) {


        return bcrypt.genSaltAsync(10).then(function(result) {
            return bcrypt.hashAsync(user.password, result, null);
        })
        .then(function(result) {
                // store in database
                console.log("stored in database!");
                return result;
            });

    };
```

Comment: I would use a different method name for sure. `users.setPassword` doesn't seem to set a password, but just computes a hash for a given one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> bcrypt.hashAsync seems to require 4 parameters. Original, non-promisified hash method requires 3 only though.

It's the other way round rather. From [the docs](https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs#api):

> `hash(data, salt, progress, cb)`
>
> - `data`  - [REQUIRED] - the data to be encrypted.
> - `salt`  - [REQUIRED] - the salt to be used to hash the password.
> - `progress`  - a callback to be called during the hash calculation to signify progress
> - `callback`  - [REQUIRED] - a callback to be fired once the data has been encrypted.

The original method took 4 arguments, `hashAsync` will take 3 and return a promise.

However, in your code you were only passing two. You don't need to pass an empty function though, that the parameter is not *[REQUIRED]* means you can pass `null` (or any other falsy value) for it. bcrypt [will create such an empty function itself](https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs/blob/1c548e558fbf0ff9c01ea708412fac1e3f377f22/bCrypt.js#L497). So use

```
function (data) {
    return bcrypt.genSaltAsync(10).then(function(result) {
        return bcrypt.hashAsync(data.password, result, null);
    });
}
```

Comment: It might be desirable to support `progress` in the promisified version too by accepting it as a second argument into the `function (data)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my promisified bcrypt from a project I did a while back. Bluebird isn't really necessary for such a small, simple library.

```
module.exports = {
   makeUser: function(username, password){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("hashing the password failed, see user.js " + err);
            reject(err);
          }
          else {
            console.log("hash was successful.");
            resolve(hash);
          }
        })
      })
    })
    .then(function(hash){
      return db.createUser(username, hash)
    })
  },

  login: function(username, password){
    return db.userFind(username)
    .then(function(userObj){
      if(!userObj){
        console.log("did not find " + username + " in database.");
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ 
          resolve({login:false, message:"Your username and/or password are incorrect."})
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log("found user: " + userObj._id, userObj);
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          bcrypt.compare(password, userObj.hashword, function(err, bool) {
            resolve({bool:bool, 
              user:userObj._id,
              mindSeal: userObj
            })
          })
        })
      } 
    })
  }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var user = handler.userExists(username)
  .then(function(answer){
    if (answer !== null){
      console.log(req.body.username + " was taken")
      res.send({login: false, message: req.body.username + " is taken"});
      return null;
    } else if (answer === null) {
      console.log("username not taken")
      return handler.makeUser(username, password);
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log("error during user lookup:", err);
    res.status(404).send({message:"database error:", error:err});
  })

  if (user !== null){
    user
    .then(function(x){
      console.log("this is returned from handler.makeUser: ", x)
      console.log(x.ops[0]._id)
      req.session.user = x.ops[0]._id;
      var mindSeal = { 
        userSettings: {
          username: x.ops[0]._id,
          newCardLimit: null,
          tValDefault: 128000000, 
          lastEdit: req.body.time, 
          todayCounter: 0,
          allTimeCounter: 0,
          cScaleDefault: {0: 0.9, 1: 1.2, 2: 1.8, 3: 2.5},
          accountMade: req.body.time
        },
        decks: {}
      };
      handler.setMindSeal(req.session.user, mindSeal, req.body.time);
      res.send({
        login: true, 
        mindSeal: mindSeal
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log("make user error: " + error);
      res.status(401).send({message:"failed.",error:error,login:false});
    })
  }

});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  handler.login(username, password)
  .then(function(obj){
    if (obj.bool){
      console.log("username and password are valid. login granted.");
      req.session.user = obj.user;
      console.log("obj is:", obj)
      var mindSeal = {decks:obj.mindSeal.decks, userSettings:obj.mindSeal.userSettings};
      console.log("mindSeal sending:", mindSeal);
      res.status(200).send({
        login: true, 
        message:"Login Successful", 
        mindSeal: obj.mindSeal
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log("password invalid")
      res.status(401).send({login: false, message:"Your username and/or password are incorrect."})
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
    res.status(404).send({message:"database error:", error:err});
  })
});
```

conceptual example only; borrowed and slightly modified some old code of mine on the fly. Working code (I see things I'd like to improve in it now, but it works) here: https://github.com/finetype/mindseal/blob/master/server.js

Answer (score -5):

Maybe you could use [another bcrypt library](https://github.com/fpirsch/twin-bcrypt), with a better API which removes the need for promises.

```
Users.prototype.setPassword = function(user) {
    return TwinBcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10);
};
```

Or, with progress tracking :

```
Users.prototype.setPassword = function(user) {

    function progress(p) {
        console.log( Math.floor(p*100) + '%' );
    }

    TwinBcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, progress, function(result) {
        // store in database
        console.log("stored in database!");
        return result;
    });

};
```

Comment: How is that library better? It still seems to have an asynchronous mode, which would benefit from using promises.

Comment: COI Disclosure (that the author should have made): the author of this answer is the author of the "better" bcrypt library mentioned.